# OPA: command line parameters documentation

Tags: command-line-arguments, opa

I was just looking for a way to tell the OPA http server what port to listen

I found this article http://blog.opalang.org/2011/06/first-steps-hello-web-in-opa.html

that talks about the --port parameter

I'd like to know where are all these parameters documented

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run `opa --help` or `man opa` ;)

Answer (score 3):

`myapp.exe --help` will print possible options for your compiled Opa app.

I agree, it would great to add a chapter about common options in the online documentation.